# Accessing static variable in quotes from inside static function

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code, which doesn't work:

```
<?php
class test{
    public static $var = 'foo';
    public static function printvar(){
        echo "Var value is {self::$var}";
    }
}
test::printvar();
?>
```

However this works:

```
<?php
class test{
    public static $var = 'foo';
    public static function printvar(){
        echo "Var value is " . self::$var;
    }
}
test::printvar();
?>
```

Question is, is there anyway I can access the static variables inside quotes from inside a static method?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: May be with sprintf() function, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By manual:

> > Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string is defined. **Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables**.

Read more [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) ...

Comment: Thanks, I did go through that page, however somehow I missed the highlighted point. :)